# Does variable_get in Drupal have major issues with memcache?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-fapi

On a few modules there is a variable_get that is pulling either the correct setting (toboggan/denied) or (node/200) even though the {variable} table is set to toboggan/denied? where is the node/200 coming from and why the randomness in values? Is this a caching issue? This problem is causing us to not be able to set admin settings on modules. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Theoretically when you update a variable, the cache should be reset for that automatically, but if you're using a bunch of heavy cache handling it might be a good idea to clear cache everywhere.
- It seems to me that if you've got a number of drupal front ends serving, that even updating variable_get on one machine would mean the other servers would have the old data in cache, which would indeed suggest clearing cache is needed.  It would also suggest why you might have the seeming randomness.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what was going on. 2 servers being served with same memcache. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Is Drupal Caching set to Normal or Aggressive? (Performance settings) I've found the Normal setting to be unpredictable, in your case, using the right variable values. Variables do get cached.